# Jquery divs slide

Tags: jquery, slide

The link: [www.goo.gl/prrRRT](http://www.goo.gl/prrRRT)

I want the div with the question mark to slide full out (like how its now) when i hover and after when im not hover then he slide back that you only see the question mark. This is my jquery for now.

```
<script>
    $('.vraagteken_container').hover(function() {
        $('.vraagteken_container').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
        $('.vraagteken_container').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the jquery `hover()` takes in two functions: in and out events...

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

so modify your code like so:

```
<script>
    $('.vraagteken_container').hover(function() {
        $('.vraagteken_container').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
},
function() {
        $('.vraagteken_container').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can u look again at the link, he will do the same

Comment: I have it now, but how i can make it, that they only see the question mark at the begin, before they hover

Comment: it is hard to tell what your code is doing. perhaps you can put an example on jsfiddle? also it looks like you might want to swap the hide/show methods...